# How to change the label of a button in primeNG in component class

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<button pButton type="button" ></button>
```

Need to set the label in the component class as "delivery address" not using the label property in the html markup.

Comment: what do you mean 'set the label'? if you want a caption just enter some text `<button ...>my button</button>`

Answer (score 3):

Just bind your class property to the `label` property of `pButton`

**HTML**

```
<button pButton type="button" label="{{customLabel}}"></button>
```

**TS**

```
customLabel = 'My custom label';
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frjcsu)

Answer (score 0):

Well, just try this :

```
  <button
   pbutton=""
   type="button"
   label="Button"
   class="p-button p-component"
  >
   <span class="p-button-label"> {{buttonLabel}}</span>
  </button>
```

In the ts file,

```
 this.buttonLabel = condition ? 'string-truthy-condition' : 'string-falsy-condition';
```